# How to use IndexOf for a range of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

```
var Myarray = [0,4,6,14,50]

var Index = Myarray.indexOf(40-50)
```

How do I write this in p5, where it returns the index of all the numbers inside a specific range?

Mistakes I could have made

1. I may be using indexOf, which is the wrong command
2. I may not know the full extent of how indexOf works
3. If there isn't a command, is it possible to use a for loop

Note: The 40-50 isn't meant to be from any specific language, it's just to show what I'm going for.

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Do you want all the indices of the array where the value is between `40` and `50`?  Do you want all the indices between the first element whose value is `40` and the first subsequent one whose value is `50`?  Do you want those elements at indices `40`, `41`, `42`, ..., `50`?  The last is a simple command, `Myarray.slice(40, 50)`, but the others are not built in.  So what are you looking for?

Comment: I want to find all the index values of any instances which the number is 40-50. (Sorry if that's phrased confusingly)

Comment: Then I would suggest a variant of the technique from @NinaScholz, namely, `const indicesForRange = (min, max) => (ns) => [...Array.keys (ns)] .filter (i => ns[i] >= min && ns[i] <= max)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the indices and filter with the wanted range.

```js
const
    array = [0, 4, 6, 14, 50],
    indices = [...array.keys()].filter(i => array[i] >= 40 && array[i] <= 50);

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` and `Array.prototype.filter()`.

```js
const numbers = [0, 4, 6, 14, 50],
    solution = numbers.map((num, i) => num >= 40 && num <= 50 ? i : -1).filter(val => val !== -1);

console.log(solution);
```

.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly. Although I do have one question, how would I change this to work in other programs? For example, which values would I have to change for different numbers or variable-based numbers? I'm relatively new to p5, and I don't know many of the commands, and what those commands do.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
var Myarray = [0, 4, 6, 14, 50]

function getElementsInRange(array, min, max) {
  return array.filter(i => (i - min) * (i - max) <= 0)
}

console.log(getElementsInRange(Myarray, 14, 50))
```

Updated thanks to @Nina Scholz.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem below might be the solution to get the indices of items in range.

```
function indicesOfIntegerRange(numbersArray, num1, num2) {
  if (!numbersArray || !numbersArray.length) {
    return [-1];
  }

  if (!num1) {
    return [numbersArray.indexOf(num2)];
  }

  if (!num2) {
    return [numbersArray.indexOf(num1)];
  }

  const min = Math.min(num1, num2);
  const max = Math.max(num1, num2);

  return numbersArray
    .filter((n) => n >= min && n <= max)
    .map((n) => numbersArray.indexOf(n));
}
```

**Usage:**

```
const numbersArray = [0, 4, 6, 14, 50];
console.log(indicesOfIntegerRange()); // [-1]
console.log(indicesOfIntegerRange([])); // [-1]
console.log(indicesOfIntegerRange(numbersArray)); // [-1]
console.log(indicesOfIntegerRange(numbersArray, 40)); // [-1]
console.log(indicesOfIntegerRange(numbersArray, 50)); // [4]
console.log(indicesOfIntegerRange(numbersArray, 40, 50)); // [4]
console.log(indicesOfIntegerRange(numbersArray, 50, 40)); // [4]
```

Hope this would help.